# Scrapy output CSV file with first column as ID

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am quite beginner with Scrapy library. I am trying to output simple CSV file from Scrapy using:

`scrapy crawl scraper -o file.csv`

where the first column gonna be basically index number of rows same way as we can do this with Pandas library using:

`pandas.to_csv(path_or_buf=name, index_label='ID')`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not clear what data is going in the CSV. Is it data you're extracting from a single web page, or a crawl of multiple pages? Where does the data come from: a table on the page or pages? One row per page? Or something else? Have you written a Spider class? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class variable and increment it for each ID:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ......
    index = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        ....
        item["ID"] = self.index
        self.index += 1
```

Comment: This solution worked exactly how I expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using [Scrapy Exporters](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#baseitemexporter). You have to either use pandas or csv package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own subclass of [`CsvItemExporter`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter) that does what you want
2. Define the [`FEED_EXPORTERS`](http://FEED_EXPORTERS) setting so that your subclass is used for CSV files. For example:

```py
    FEED_EXPORTERS = {'csv': 'my_project.exporters.MyCsvItemExporter'}
```